# jFormattedTextField's Formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true) doesn't work at first focus

Tags: java, swing, event-listener, propertychanged, jformattedtextfield

I have a `jFormattedTextField` and I set `setCommitsOnValidEdit` to true then I added an event listener to "property change" on "value" property.

At first focus of that `jFormattedTextField` it doesn't call event listener method when typing in it. But on "focusLost" it calls event listener and after that when it receives focus again it calls event listener when typing.

I want the event listener be called after any change in any time in that `jFormattedTextField` (Even in the fist focus).

What's the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: What technology are you talking about?

Comment: jFormattedTextField in J2SE's Swing

Comment: What is `setCommitsOnValidEdit`?

Comment: Hi; Excuse me i meant it's `jFormattedTextField`'s `Formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit`

Comment: would suggest you track why the commitOnValid doesn't work as expected instead of adding tons of hack-around code, which'll bite you sometime in future :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you have to look at [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

EDIT:

I know this issue from my 1st touch of `JFormattedTextField`, here comings example that isn't works at firts `focusLost` :-) and probably demonstrated your issue

minimum limit is there set at `10.000,-` for both `JFormattedTextField`,

1st. `JFormattedTextField` handling `FocusListener` (output must be delayed into `invokeLater`)

2nd. `JFormattedTextField` handling `DocumentListener` (works every...)

inital look

[image]

here is same problem, because I put here only 500,- and on focusLost nothing changed, correct amount must be >= `10.000,-`

[image]

on 2dn. `focusLost` works ....

[image]

no idea how is that possible, but solved by wrapping into `invokeLater()`, then works on 1st. `focusLost` (you have to uncomment these code lines)

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class FormatterLimit {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    private JLabel focusLabel = new JLabel(" focusLost Handle ");
    private JFormattedTextField formTextField;
    private JLabel docLabel = new JLabel(" document Handle ");
    private JFormattedTextField formTextField1;
    private NumberFormat formTextFieldFormat;
    private double amount = 10000.00;

    public FormatterLimit() {
        formTextFieldFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formTextFieldFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        formTextFieldFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        formTextFieldFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        focusLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        focusLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        focusLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 27));
        formTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formTextFieldFormat);
        formTextField.setValue(amount);
        formTextField.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));
        formTextField.setForeground(Color.black);
        formTextField.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        formTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 27));
        formTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        formTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                formTextField.requestFocus();
                formTextField.setText(formTextField.getText());
                formTextField.selectAll();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                //Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                //@Override
                //public void run() {
                double t1a1 = (((Number) formTextField.getValue()).doubleValue());
                if (t1a1 < 1000) {
                    formTextField.setValue(amount);
                }
                //}
                // };
                //SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);

            }
        });

        docLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        docLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        docLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 27));

        formTextField1 = new JFormattedTextField(formTextFieldFormat);
        formTextField1.setValue(amount);
        formTextField1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));
        formTextField1.setForeground(Color.black);
        formTextField1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        formTextField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 27));
        formTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        formTextField1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                formTextField1.requestFocus();
                formTextField1.setText(formTextField1.getText());
                formTextField1.selectAll();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            }
        });
        formTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(docListener);

        pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        pnl.add(focusLabel);
        pnl.add(formTextField);
        pnl.add(docLabel);
        pnl.add(formTextField1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        formTextFieldFocus1();
    }
    //
    private DocumentListener docListener = new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            printIt(documentEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            printIt(documentEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            printIt(documentEvent);
        }

        private void printIt(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
            double t1a1 = (((Number) formTextField1.getValue()).doubleValue());
            if (t1a1 < 1000) {
                Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        formTextField1.setValue(amount);
                    }
                };
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
            }
        }
    };

    private void formTextFieldFocus1() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                formTextField1.grabFocus();
                formTextField1.requestFocus();
                formTextField1.setText(formTextField1.getText());
                formTextField1.selectAll();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private void formTextFieldFocus() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                formTextField.grabFocus();
                formTextField.requestFocus();
                formTextField.setText(formTextField.getText());
                formTextField.selectAll();
                formTextFieldFocus1();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FormatterLimit fl = new FormatterLimit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803976/focusevent-doesnt-get-the-last-value-of-jformattedtextfield-how-i-can-get-it/6804749).

Comment: Hi; `invokeLater` had no effect! But `DocumentListener` Worked; Thanks

Comment: :-) for that is there second method invoked not formTextFieldFocus1() but formTextFieldFocus(), glad to help anyway +1

Answer (score 3):

Actually, setCommitOnValidEdit should work always as you expect (and does in the code snippet below), no need for a DocumentListener, after all, the method is exactly for that purpose. So I suspect something else is wrong in your context. Or for some reason the very first edit isn't parsed to anything valid?

```
    NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter( 
            NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
    // allow or not doesn't make a difference
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);  
    numberFormatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
    JFormattedTextField readTimeOut = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatter);
    PropertyChangeListener l = new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            LOG.info("got new value: " + evt.getNewValue());
        }
    };
    readTimeOut.addPropertyChangeListener("value", l);
    readTimeOut.setColumns(20);
    readTimeOut.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);    

    JFormattedTextField other = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatter);
    other.addPropertyChangeListener("value", l);
    other.setColumns(20);
    other.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);    
    JPanel box = new JPanel();
    box.add(readTimeOut);
    box.add(other);
```

Comment: both are hard Listened that doesn't love another Listeners together +1