# JTextPane Syntax-Highlight - Restricting my formatting?

Tags: java, html, swing, syntax-highlighting, jtextpane

I'm currently programming an IDE, and am using a JTextPane as the "code-editor".

Now, I am trying to add syntax highlighting to the JTextPane, but am having some trouble...

I'm using HTML to replace http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/6185/910b3b10cad4487f9c96d43.png with [image: Green Comment] :

```
private void jTextPane1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    

        String SyntaxedCode = jTextPane1.getText();

        jTextPane1.setText(SyntaxedCode.replaceAll("//", "<span style='color: green'>//</span>"));

}
```

Getting The Result:

[image]

Now, the part I'm struggling with, is the fact that the JTextPane is limiting my spacing...
I can only add one or two spaces in a row, and then the JTextPane just stops accepting spaces.
Also, I can't use the enter key to go to a new line.

Why is it restricting me like this, and how can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: For the love of all things holy, someone has to have already made one for Java classes. Please make this public, somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) for listening events from keyboard to the [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html), then you have implements [DocumentListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283334/jformattedtextfields-formatter-setcommitsonvalidedittrue-doesnt-work-at-firs/7284706#7284706)

2) in the case of you want to filtering, block or modify inputs from keyboard, and before this contents will be diplayed in the GUI, then you have look for [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429459/get-a-key-from-jtextarea/9430683#9430683)

3) I'd suggest to implements [Highlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/714968), sure is possible to use Html formatted text, then better is to create own [HtlmEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.Parser.html)

4) forgot for listeng in the [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) by using [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)