# Java: How cursor automatically move from one TextField to other

Tags: java, swing, awt

In my application four TextArea is there and I want to enter only four character in one Text area and cursor automatically move to next TestArea. Again when I enter four character in this TextArea then again cursor automatically move to next TextArea.

Example: At the time of installing Window XP it want "Key" and there are four section when you enter four character in first section then cursor automatically move to the next section.

Same thing I want in my application.

For this first of all I add CustomizedTextFields.jar and then created four IntegerField:

```
private IntegerField text1;
private IntegerField text2;
private IntegerField text3;
private IntegerField text4;
```

after this I show all these IntegerField on my frame.

Now I tried this code to send cursor to the next field but it's not working:

```
text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    int a2 = text1.getText().length();
                    if (a2 == 3) {
                        text2.getCursor();
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

interesting enough question to try improving my shadowy knowledge of the text package :-)

There are two separate requirements here

- restrict the lenght of the text: that's done with a DocumentFilter as @mKorbel already noted
- automatically transferFocus to the next component after the max length is reached: turns out that can be done with a NavigationFilter

in code:

```
JComponent panel = new JPanel();
final int maxSize = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    final JTextField field = new JTextField(5);
    NavigationFilter filter = new NavigationFilter() {

        @Override
        public void setDot(FilterBypass fb, int dot, Bias bias) {
            if (dot >= maxSize) {
                fb.setDot(0, bias);
                field.transferFocus();
                return;
            }
            fb.setDot(dot, bias);
        }

        @Override
        public void moveDot(FilterBypass fb, int dot, Bias bias) {
            if (dot >= maxSize) { 
                fb.setDot(0, bias);
                field.transferFocus();
                return;
            }
            fb.moveDot(dot, bias);
        }

    };
    field.setNavigationFilter(filter);
    ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentSizeFilter(maxSize));
    panel.add(field);
}
```

The documentFilter is the one from the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: @Vinit Vikash and this is answer to your question

Comment: @kleopatra : +1 for NavigationFilter. Actually , till today, this term was not in my knowledge :-) . Still reading about this, feels like what you had told is the way to go, since I was hoping that someone can put more light on this, that's why I posted the answer, else I never wanted to.

Comment: But, when I applied `transferFocus()` inside `NavigationFilter`, nothing changed, so If you may, post the whole code, I shall be really obliged.

Comment: @GagandeepBali that _is_ the whole code - simply  throw it into your favourite frame and run it :-)

Comment: Now it's working, LOL, last time it gave me all sorts of wicked errors. Just one thing, change the `maxSize` to 4, as OP wants for 4 Characters. Deleting my answer :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
At the time of installing Window XP it want "Key" and there are four section 
when you enter four character in first section then cursor automatically move 
to the next section.
```

1. add [DocumentListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283334/jformattedtextfields-formatter-setcommitsonvalidedittrue-doesnt-work-at-firs/7284706#7284706) to the `JTextComponents`, for listening add [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968)
2. don't use `KeyListener` for `JTextComponents`, use only `DocumentListener`
3. add required next `JTextArea` to the `DocumentListener`, if is there typed 4th. Char into `JTextArea`,
4. notice, moving with `Focus` from one `JTextArea` to another would be better wrapped into `invokeLater`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `text2.getCursor()` with `text2.requestFocus()`.

`getCursor()` is for retrieving the shape of the mouse pointer when hovering over a component.

Also, with this method it is still possible to enter more than 4 chars in a field, for example by pasting from clipboard. If you want to block that, you would need to check if text entered is longer than 4 chars, and if so, take only first 4 chars from it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
             String value=text1.getText();
             if(value.length()==4){
             text2.requestFocus();
          }
}
```

Where text2 is your next textfield

Comment: don't use keyListeners at all ... especially not for validating text input, instead see @mKorbel's answer

Answer (score 0):

simply just create textarea and go to key typed events 
den u may write this

```
String number=jTextArea1.getText();
 int l=number.length();
 if(l==3){
 jTextArea1.transferFocus();

 }
```